# What does __db.001 mean in Berkeley Database?

Tags: berkeley-db

i'm using berkeley db and i'm new to it.
I have noticed that whenever i start the berkeley the file " __db.001" is created in my directory
and it consists of 1 line

May you please explain to me what is the use of that file?

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These files are used by Berkeley DB internally by the shared environment (DBEnv) to coordinate multi-process access to the database.

See also [___db.001](http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/help/BerkeleyDB/ref/env/region.html)

Comment: Hello, in my system, the __db.001 file consists of one line only. Does this matter? Also,is the __db.001 file related to DB_CONFIG file?Thanks

Comment: There is very few information out on ___db.001 so I would just leave it at "It is a system file for Berkeley DB".